# Create direct url to LinkedIn company update

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm implementing a Compony newsfeed on a website and ran into the following problem. The LinkedIn API doesn't provide a direct URL to a company update. Looking at the LinkedIn site there are direct URL's and they're like this for example: 
`https://www.linkedin.com/company/1441/comments?topic=5849556347070205952&type=U&scope=1441&stype=C&a=5uHW&goback=%2Ebzo_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_1441`

Trying stuff out it seems that the parameters topic, type, scope, stype and a are mandatory for the URL to work.. (goback is the only one that isn't).

Using the LinkedIn API with the [Company updates call](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates) I'm able to buid the direct url, except for the `a` parameter. The value is always 4  (for me unexplainable) characters long.

Has anyone ever successfully build a direct URL to a company update or can someone maybe explain the `a` parameter or how to generate its value?

Comment: How were you parsing out the topic id?  I only see it as part of the `updateKey` in the response - need to play string games to extract it...

Comment: @allicarn yeah I indeed expect some string(split) games...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Updated to new format

You can link directly to any update (company or user) using the following url:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:[topic_id]
```

You can get [topic_id] by getting the last bit of the updateKey in [the api response](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates) from Linkedin. When updateKey = UPDATE-c7352-6410848097894756353, your topic_id = 6410848097894756353.

In your example that would become https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:5849556347070205952 which links directly to the specific update. *The post is too old to work with the new link format*

---

**The url used to be**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates/?topic=[topic_id]
```

Updated thanks to the comment from @sethpollack

Comment: this URL scheme no longer works. the new one is: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:[topic_id]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to get the **topic id** from the API response object (as already commented on the OP question), the **topic id** is the value after the last hyphen of the `updateKey` property, which can be used with @Daan answer:

```
"updateKey": "UPDATE-cXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
```

Direct URL:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates?topic=[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY]
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was trying to use the 'id' field but I didn't work. Thought the url from @Daan was obsolete! :P

Answer (score 0):

Using the URL format above, get the topic_id by opening the update in its own window/tab, look at the page source code in your browser and search for the string  :activity:   the long number after the string is the infamous topic_id