# LinkedIn Company Update permalink

Tags: linkedin-api

Based on the [current API docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages) (*2015 edition*), the API allows for

- Reading a Company's updates
- Posting to a Company updates

However, the sample responses do not seem to include any form of "permalink". If you post a Company update it gets added to Company's feed, but there's no specific link that I can send to others.

**Am I missing something, do Company Updates have a permalink?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create direct url to LinkedIn company update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915856/create-direct-url-to-linkedin-company-update)

Comment: Based on the time stamps, the other one is "the duplicate". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the company update key value & apply in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915856/create-direct-url-to-linkedin-company-update/27380234#27380234).

According to the above link, here is an example.

If update key is UPDATE-c1337-998877665544332211, then the permalink will be https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates?topic=998877665544332211

Comment: Is that in the docs somewhere or is this undocumented behaviour that just happens to work?

Comment: Its not in the LinkedIn API docs. I'm using since couple of months before. Its working so far.